# DataGrid- How to access Row.IsSelected from within a Column (in xaml)

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I've got a DataGrid with a few columns, and rows.

For a selected row- I'd like to display a combobox (bound to a list of strings) for each column.

For a row that's not selected, I'd like to display a TextBlock with the selected string.

I'm aiming to do it using a binding within the DataGridColumnTemplate (and perhaps a style like here [How to display combo box as textbox in WPF via a style template trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479936/how-to-display-combo-box-as-textbox-in-wpf-via-a-style-template-trigger)). How would I go about going to "Row.IsSelected" from within the Column's CellTemplate ? I suppose I need to do go up the visual tree to the Row?

Answer (score 3):

> I suppose I need to do go up the visual tree to the Row?

Yes, you could use a RelativeSource to bind to any property of the parent DataGridRow in your CellTemplate:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" />
```

So something like this should work:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmb">
                <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="..." Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="cmb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```